# How to handle backpressed (keyDown - in previous version) in order to show a confirm dialog for exit the application?

Tags: android, dialog, back, android-softkeyboard

I've made the logic for showing a confirm dialog when the user press back button by overriding backPressed method, but this implies an unusual behaviour. If soft input keyboard is shown, on back key event, it must be hidden and other back key event must launch the confirmation dialog. There is a way to achieve this? Maybe by detecting  if soft input keyboard is up and bypass the confirmation dialog?

Here is a code sample to make this clear:

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
    {
              //here is the mystery 
              if (soft keyboard is visible)
              {
                    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
              } else
              {
                                //method which shows the close dialog and close the application
                    onBackPressed();
                    return true;
              }
    }
              return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if soft keyboard is shown ,I don't think Activity can receive back key event. the default behaviour is back key make soft keyboard disappear.

View also can block key event, the simple way is setOnKeyListener. make sure that your View is focusable and when it receive back key event just return true .

Comment: Yes, you're right. A real problem was that i have been overrided both onKeyDown and onKeyUp and that made a double backPressed to be called. Now i have only onKeyDown overrided and soft keyboard consumes the event. Another strange behaviour has been encountered, that is when a new back key event is caught the onBackPressed is ignored. I have to handle it. Thank you for a good answear.

Answer (score 1):

Code to hide the softkey pad :

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

you can put this code onBackKeyPressed no matter keyboard is showing or not

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My real issue is that Keyboard consumes my back event and then close confirm dialog is shown (same back event). What I really want is to make a logic that shows the confirm dialog  only when there is no interference on the screen (soft keyboard, spinner dropdown, etc...).